# How long does it take to create an Alexa Skill?

Tags: smart-home, alexa, software

Generally speaking, how long does it take to create an Alexa skill?

Clearly "it depends", so let's assume someone has programming experience, and the thing to control has an easy to call API.

On the surface it seems trivial. If words spoken, then call api. Mixin a few variations for usability.  But most (all?) things are harder to code than they seem at first glance.

One example is the [new AV support](https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/alexa/post/78f44d51-5bdf-4a4c-8eaa-57d1282c8212/introducing-entertainment-capabilities-in-alexa-smart-home-new-device-controls-for-tvs-av-receivers-and-ir-hubs). Thinking about creating a skill for Onkyo receivers, since they don't seem to be working on it.

Comment: I think the answer is so much, "it depends," that we can't really give you a useful answer. If you have programming experience, it's probably going to be quicker than if you don't. Even experienced developers aren't great at predicting project times, and I think it might just be the wrong question here. It might be more productive to just give it a go and ask questions here if you have any problems, because any answer we give will almost certainly not be right, and won't be much use to you.

Comment: If you're unfamiliar with Alexa development, maybe try [Building a Trivia Skill in under an Hour](https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/post/TxDJWS16KUPVKO/New-Alexa-Skills-Kit-Template:-Build-a-Trivia-Skill-in-under-an-Hour) which might help you predict the time needed. Good luck!

Comment: I'm afraid predicting project lengths really isn't that simple, and 
would be affected by factors such as your experience, the difficulty of the project, etc. It's not a question that can be answered accurately, so I don't think anyone can give you a date that will really be helpful to you. Stack Exchange sites aren't great at giving you answers to questions that require more estimation and opinion than verifiable fact, unfortunately. I'm not really sure if my comment really counts as an answer to "How long does it take to create an Alexa skill?" though; perhaps [edit] to clarify first.

Comment: @Aurora0001 its true, but irrelevant here, that predicting project lengths in general is not simple. What matters here is the predictability of a Alexa skill project, not projects in general. Of course it can't be exact, the benefit is having a ROM level of effort before spending a couple of hours in the SDK.  Having now spent the two hours doing that and reading your link, I can tell you without doubt the question can be answered not with precision, but certainly in a way that could be useful.

Comment: Questions of this sort are considered inappropriate in the stack exchange system overall.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I assume you are referring to a question being "answerable"?  I've tried to explain that it's answerable due to having a specific and limited scope. Are you saying the specificity and limited scope of the problem still make it impossible to provide a useful answer?  Or are you referring to something else in the SE faqs?

Comment: To try to clarify, the biggest reason I believe this question is ok is because of something I think most people here would agree with: One of the hardest things about software or hardware development is integration, making things work together, because it's often hard even when it should be easy.  Most often I don't see late projects because engineers couldn't grasp difficult concepts, or because the theory was wrong. In this case, what should be the most risky part of a project, mastery of the device, the device api, the integration, has been intentionally excluded.

Comment: @Lee please integrate your clarifications into the question itself. It will also automatically prompt the question to enter the *reopen review queue* in which people can vote to reopen your question.

Comment: @Lee I certainly think this can be edited into a question that *can* be answered with a little bit of work, and be something that is also more useful to other readers in the future. Perhaps think about which bits you were thinking you needed to do when you create a skill, and ask how to do that with Alexa. E.g. asking whether you would have to build the communication code yourself or whether there is an API to support it might be more factual, but could still lead to answers that help you estimate the time needed. I hope you're able to do that, because this is an important question.